# How to fetch the data Two service based sql server in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have to retrive the data from one service based sql server to another service based sql server

```
select * from servernameA.db_name.dbo.table_name 
where column in (select column from servernameb.db_name.dbo.table_name)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ across multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352949/linq-across-multiple-databases)

Comment: And where is EF here?

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem? You can do it.

Just a little performance improvement in your query with `DISTINCT`.

```
select * from servernameA.db_name.dbo.table_name 
where column in (select DISTINCT column from servernameb.db_name.dbo.table_name)
```

For your reference:
[Query across multiple databases on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611310/query-across-multiple-databases-on-same-server)
[Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

**------------Edit----------------**
How about this? I haven't tried this yet. Give this a try.

```
// connectionString is the connection string for the ServerA..DB1
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     conn.Open();
     // provide commandText as the SQL query having the full name of Server2..DB2
     using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
     {
         using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while(reader.Read())
              {
                  // read the result
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I want to run C# So Please give me the sample code for C#

Comment: Thanks For your reply but .... Give me sample code for how to select data from one sql server to another sql server    ..........                                                                          select * from servernameA.db_name.dbo.table_name 
where column in (select column from servernameb.db_name.dbo.table_name)