# SQL use value from local table to reference table in different DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This may not be possible ;^)

I'm trying to pull together billing and performance data from separate client dbs.  The "core" db has a table like so:

```
client_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
client_db_name VARCHAR(100), 
...
```

Each client_db has a table, `orders`, with columns `order_date` and `order_total`.

Conceptually, I'd like to be able to use the `client_db_name` in a query:

```
SELECT  SUM(order_total) AS sales
FROM    {client_db_name}.orders AS o
WHERE   o.order_date LIKE '2021%'
```

Questions:

1. is this even possible?
2. if so, how would I JOIN this query?  What would the `ON` be?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611310/query-across-multiple-databases-on-same-server

Comment: This [link](https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/1059-how-to-query-across-multiple-databases) will be of great help I believe.

Comment: Thanks, @Salvino, but neither of these actually speaks to the problem I'm trying to solve.  As I said, it may be unsolveable given the architecture, because there's no way I've found to make the `{db_name}` component of `{db_name}.table_name.column_name` resolve dynamically.

Comment: Can't you just interpolate the string value in the query with code and then execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

No interpolation.

A Stored procedure might be able to perform the interpolation via `CONCAT`, `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Wouldn't it be better the have all the customers in the same table?  That would make it all easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic query, a query that is the result of another query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(query_piece SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM (SELECT CONCAT("SELECT '", client_db_name, "' AS client, SUM(order_total) AS sales FROM ", client_db_name, '.orders o WHERE YEAR(o.order_date) = 2021') AS query_piece
        FROM core.clients) AS sq
```

My query will return a dynamic query like this (I have two clients into core.clients table: a and b):

```
SELECT 'a' AS client, SUM(order_total) AS sales FROM a.orders o WHERE YEAR(o.order_date) = 2021 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'b' AS client, SUM(order_total) AS sales FROM b.orders o WHERE YEAR(o.order_date) = 2021
```

The dynamic query will return something like this:

| client | sales |
| --- | --- |
| a | 50.00 |
| b | 100.00 |